# What do the messages in Doge2048 say when you're shifting tiles?

Tags: doge2048

When I play this game I see comments flashing on the screen so fast I can't read most of them. The few I can read seem to be from someone who speaks English as a second language; looks like native language may be Japanese or Chinese. Does anybody know what they all say?

Answer (score 3):

Looking at the game's source code through Inspect Element, one of the scripts used by the game ([html_actuator.js](http://doge2048.com/js/html_actuator.js)) uses the variable `dogeSayings` containing an array of all the possible messages that can be said.

```
var dogeSayings = ['such good', 'so amaze', 'many points', 'very unstoppable', 'great jorb', 'such playing', 'very good', 'points', 'very gaming', 'such player', 'concern' ,'bewildered',
'many game', 'so good', 'very scores', 'so scoring', 'so hot right now', 'such playing', 'such matching', 'so matched', 'very matched', 'very neat' ,'such natural',]
```

I would mostly assume that the grammar used for these does not have anything to do with the developer's knowledge of English, but simply because of the [nature of the Doge meme](http://knowyourmeme.com/memes/doge).